# Unable to establish a connection with a Bluetooth device with mfeet32.net: : "The requested address is not valid in context"

Tags: vb.net, bluetooth

I am trying using 32feet.net with vb.net with a Innateck bluetooth scanner.
The model is an Innateck scanner model BCST-70 (BCST-70-1910090473 exactly).
The scanner is correcty reconnised by Windows 10.

I'm using VisualStudio2015 with .net 4.6.1 and InTheHand.Net.Personal Version=3.5.605.0.

The discovery function of 32feet.net (DiscoverDevices ()) displays device information like:

- Device name        : BCST-70-1910090473
- Device address : 211910090473
- Device Sap : 269026419
- Device Nap : 8473

My connection code is :

```
    Dim addr As BluetoothAddress = Nothing
    Dim sp As Guid = Nothing
    Dim ep As BluetoothEndPoint = Nothing 
    Dim cli As BluetoothClient = Nothing

    addr = BluetoothAddress.Parse("34885D4719A9")
    sp = BluetoothService.HumanInterfaceDevice
    ep = New BluetoothEndPoint(addr, sp)

    Try
        cli = New BluetoothClient(ep) ' <-- error accured here
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
```

The error is:

Exception levée : 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' dans System.dll
The requested address is not valid in context

Whta is the correct address to use ? Is it a GUID probleme ? I have try to use this code with sp = Guid.Parse("e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974") (see the screenshot) but it is the same way.

Any idea ?

Thank you.

[image: Class GUID of the barcod scanner]

Comment: You can not connect to HID profile because it is L2CAP based profile as Windows supports only RFCOMM profiles. All you can do is just "install driver" fpr HID Bluetooth device.

Comment: Hello Mike and thank you for your answer,

I am afraid of not understanding well. The codbar scanner device is correctly connected to Windows system and dialog correctly (it can read a barcode and send it into the notepad for example)?
I also have the same error with my Bluetooth keyboard.
If the devices were not using the correct bluetooth protocol, they couldn't even be recognized by Windows, right?

Comment: There is no way to connect to L2CAP profiles (HID in your case) from user-mode. Only RFCOMM level is accessable. However, it is possible on driver level, that is why Winodws can communicate with such device. But no way to talk to the device through Bluetooth directly from user mode application (no L2CAP connection is avvailable).

Comment: Actually Windows provides only one way to communicate through L2CAP on user level: it is SDP connect. That is why your application can discover services. But visible services does not mean that your can connect to each of them. You can connect to RFCOMM based services (profiles) only.

Comment: When you use Add Bluetooth device dialog Windows discovers services and installs drivers for each supported service. In case of your scanner Windows installs Bluetooth HID driver and the device appears as HID (I guess it appears as keyboard)..

Comment: Thanks for your answers Mike,

You are right it is my problem ...

I will apply another method by implementing Keyboard Hooks to intercept all keystrokes because the scanner is considered as such.

It works by this way :-) ...

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: In fact there should no problem to worj with your scanner directly as with HID device using HID API (after scanner has been installed/paired by Windows). It is not possible throught Bluetooth directly, but once driver installed you can talk to your device with HID API cause it appears as HID device for the system.

Comment: Hello,

Yes, you are right again.
I found a very simple example of using the HID driver for my scanner.
It work perfectly.

http://www.janaxelson.com/hidpage.htm

Thanks again :-)

Comment: The next step is to use BluetoothSetServiceState to install and uninstall your device's driver from your application so user does not need to use Windows Add Bluetooth Device dialog.